# How to send email via exchange server without using smtp?

Tags: c#, email

I'm trying to send an email from c# code via our company's exchange server.

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("exchangebox1.mycompany.com");
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("Me@myCompany.com",
                "Them@mycompany.com",
                "title here",
                "body here");
            client.Send(msg);
```

When I run this I get SmptException saying "Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was 4.3.2 Service not available, closing transmission channel".

I'm interpreting this to mean SMTP is not enabled on our exchange box and that I need to use native Exchange Server commands to send the mail. Is this right, or should SMTP always work?

Additionally, is it possible the exchange server could have been configured to only allow certain computers/users to send main via SMTP?

How can I send mail via the Exchange Server without using SMTP?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have forwarding enabled on the account that you are sending the email as? I think it's something the Exchange admin needs to set on that account to allow you to send email with that account without using authentication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [WCF Exchange Server Mail Transport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397812.aspx)
an example of how to implement is [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397828.aspx)

Specifically regarding sending messages it says

> When an application sends a message,
>   it calls the Send method on the
>   current output channel, which must be
>   open. The output channel serializes
>   the message to a string and creates
>   the message in the Drafts folder. It
>   sets the appropriate values in the
>   e-mail fields. When the message has
>   been created, it is moved into the
>   Outbox. This occurs through CEMAPI on
>   the device or through Exchange Web
>   Services on the desktop. On the
>   device, messages in the Outbox are
>   synchronized with other outgoing
>   messages, as defined by ActiveSync.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new Exchange Web Services Managed API 1.0.  it seems to be the best solution.
heres the link.

<strike>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637749(v=exchg.80).aspx</strike>
https://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2009/04/21/3407328.aspx
The accept will accept distribution lists as well.

The 2.0 version of the API
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633709.aspx

Comment: "This Topic Is No Longer Available", so don't go there!

Comment: Just a little link rot.  I substituted an alternate, and added a link to the 2.0 version of the API.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding these two lines prior to sending:

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client.EnableSsl = true;
```

It's most likely an issue with there being no credentials so I'll cheat a little from Google...
[From dailycode.net](http://www.dailycode.net/blog/post/Service-not-available,-closing-transmission-channel.-The-server-response-was-4.3.2-Service-not-available,-closing-transmission-channel.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm afraid I get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but for completeness, you should consider the **Microsoft Exchange WebServices** nuget package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();  
service.AutodiscoverUrl("youremailaddress@yourdomain.com");  

EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);  
message.Subject = "my subject";  
message.Body = "my body";  
message.ToRecipients.Add("my_target@example.com");  
message.Save();  

message.SendAndSaveCopy();
```